# Assinging element's hover css properties to some other element

Tags: jquery, css

I have an anchor tag with some css hover selection property assigned. This CSS is auto-generated by the system.

```
a.abcClass{
    color: GREEN;
}
a.abcClass:hover{
    color: RED;
}
```

I would like to assign above given hover CSS dynamically using jQuery. Like I would like to achieve this:

$("a.abcClass").addClass(":hover")

How this can be done ?

Edit: hover properties will be applied only when mouse will be hover over that element. What if I want to have hover effect on anchor tag when some button is clicked. As this CSS is autogrnerated I don't know about its css properties.

Comment: So you want to overwrite the auto-generated CSS with jQuery?

Comment: I just want to use that. In the given case I want to use "a.abcClass:hover".

Comment: But you want all `a.abcClass` to look like `a.abcClass:hover`?

Comment: See Edit portion of Question for details.

Comment: OP, you can't add `pseudo-classes` in css like that. Just make a new class (no hover etc) and add that one.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question correctly but by any chance are looking to dynamically get all properties of an element and assign it to another element? If so, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element

Comment: Yeah something like that, but hover properties are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```js
$('.abcClass').css('color','red');
```

Comment: I dont know whats in there in that property as it is auto-generated.

Comment: I think I gotcha.  You need to be able to get the properties of `.abcClass:hover`, whatever they are, and then apply them back to `.abcClass`?

Comment: @hungstar: I don't have enough reputation to down-vote anyone.

Answer (score 0):

**Handle Hover state using jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $('.abcClass').hover( function(){
          $(this).css('color', 'red');
    });
});
```

**Handle both states using jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
   $('.abcClass').hover( function(){
      $(this).css('color', 'red');
   },
   function(){
      $(this).css('color', 'green');
   });
});
```

Sample Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VcEf4/

Comment: When passing as an object, I don't think you need the quotes around the key.

Answer (score -1):

```
a.abcClass{
    color: GREEN;
}
a.abcClass:hover, .my_epic_stylez {
    color: RED;
}
```

And:

```
$(".my_epic_stylez").addClass(":hover");
```

You can't add `pseudo-classes` like you are trying to do. The same goes for adding `:before` and `:after`-classes too.

Comment: Yeah I know I cant add, I am just giving example of what I am trying to achieve (with some other syntax).